# jQuery Validate Not Displaying Error Message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

I have a form that requires validation.  I use jQuery validation.  I have problem displaying the error message.  This is my javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submission-form").validate({
        rules: {
            WorkOrderId: "required",
            ActivityId: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            WorkOrderId: "Please choose WO",
            ActivityId: "Please choose activity"
        }
    });
});
```

Below is my html:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Submissions", FormMethod.Post , new { id = "submission-form" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                <legend>WorkOrderSubmission</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkOrderId, "WorkOrder")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList("WorkOrderId", (SelectList)ViewBag.WorkOrders, "", new { @data_rule_required="true", @data_msg_required="The Workorder field is required." })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkOrderId)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivityId, "Activity")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ActivityId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Activities, "", new { @data_rule_required="true", @data_msg_required="The Activity field is required." })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActivityId)
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        }
```

When I click the Submit, I can see the class addition on the element, but no error message is displayed.
Before submit:

```
<select data-msg-required="The Workorder field is required." data-rule-required="true" id="WorkOrderId" name="WorkOrderId" aria-required="true">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">WO000001 - 001</option>
    <option value="2">WO000002 - 001</option>
</select>
```

After submit:

```
<select data-msg-required="The Workorder field is required." data-rule-required="true" id="WorkOrderId" name="WorkOrderId" aria-required="true" class="input-validation-error" aria-describedby="WorkOrderId-error" aria-invalid="true">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">WO000001 - 001</option>
    <option value="2">WO000002 - 001</option>
</select>
```

How do I display the error message?

The generated html:

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <select data-msg-required="The Workorder field is required." data-rule-required="true" id="WorkOrderId" name="WorkOrderId"><option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">WO000001 - 001</option>
    <option value="2">WO000002 - 001</option>
  </select>
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="WorkOrderId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="ActivityId">Activity</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <select data-msg-required="The Activity field is required." data-rule-required="true" id="ActivityId" name="ActivityId">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Activity 1</option>
    <option value="22">Activity 22</option>
  </select>
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ActivityId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I have the tags `data-msg-required="The Workorder field is required." data-rule-required="true"`, but I can't see the error message.

Comment: Why are you not using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` so all this is handles out of the box (your scripts are unnecessary)?

Comment: It's actually showing the data-fule-required and data-msg-required attributes, but it's not showing the error message.

Comment: `data-rule-required` and `data-msg-required` have nothing at all to do with unobtrusive client side validation - they are just some arbitrary html attributes you have manually added yourself. Add the `[Required]` attribute to your `WorkOrderId` and `ActivityId` properties and include `jquery.validatate.unobrusive.js` in your view and it will all work fine with out your scripts (and remove those attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your options have value, 
since the first option is selected default, form seems valid.

If you add "Choose..." option at top with value of "", error message shown at form submit.

```
<option value="">Choose...</option>
```

---

Eric, I made a quick demo and I made mistakes exactly below order;

First,

make sure you add jquery validation bundle to the _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

and then

```
@Html.DropDownList("WorkOrderId", (SelectList)ViewBag.WorkOrders, "", new { @required = "required" })
```

adding required is enough, validate method adds other properties for you.

and lastly add your script code in script section:

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#submission-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    WorkOrderId: "required",
                    ActivityId: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    WorkOrderId: "Please choose WO",
                    ActivityId: "Please choose activity"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

---

```
    //   excludePropertyErrors:
    //   true to have the summary display model-level errors only, or false to have
    //   the summary display all errors.
    public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool excludePropertyErrors);
```

Comment: The very first option is empty.

Comment: why not just adding, new {required = "required"}

Comment: with/without the required attribute, the form is still not submitting.  The border turns red when I press the submit button.  My problem is the message "Please choose WO" and "Please choose activity" do not appear. How do I make the message appear?

Comment: Can you check if you have Jquery validation configuration in your code, for ex: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement

Comment: `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`   I have updated my answer.